# Is there a way to insert the most frequently occurring value in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to INSERT data from one table into another after doing a quick calculation in MySQL as to compare the user's transaction amounts (500, 150 and 100) by their total sums (500 * 2 = 1000, 150 * 3 = 450, 100 * 5 = 500) and INSERT the transaction amount with the highest sum (500) into another table (donationrequests) as the ASK.

How can I compare multiple records and then INSERT only one in MySQL? I'm struggling with this part. Below is my schema and where I am at currently.

```
CREATE TABLE transactions
(
  DONOR_ID TINYTEXT NOT NULL,
  TRANSACTION_AMT INT
);

INSERT INTO transactions
(
  DONOR_ID, TRANSACTION_AMT
) VALUES 
("ALLEN", 500 ),
("ALLEN", 500 ),
("ALLEN", 150 ),
("ALLEN", 150 ),
("ALLEN", 150 ),
("ALLEN", 100 ),
("ALLEN", 100 ),
("ALLEN", 100 ),
("ALLEN", 100 ),
("ALLEN", 100 )

CREATE TABLE donationrequests
(
  DONOR_ID TINYTEXT NOT NULL,
  ASK int
  PRIMARY KEY (USER)
);
```

```
INSERT INTO donationrequests (DONOR_ID, ASK)
SELECT DISTINCT DONOR_ID AS d, SUM(TRANSACTION_AMT) AS t
FROM transactions
GROUP BY d
ORDER BY t DESC;
```

This produces ("ALLEN", 1950) in donationrequests
It should produce ("ALLEN", 500)

Comment: why 500 is highest?

Comment: *compare the user's transaction amounts (500, 150 and 100) by their total sums (500 * 2 = 1000, 150 * 3 = 450, 100 * 5 = 500) and INSERT the transaction amount with the highest sum (500)* o_O 1000 is the highest sum, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but what I am trying to insert into ASK is the donation amount, not the sum of all donations of that amount. So I'm trying to compare the sums of all donation amounts and then whichever is highest, insert that donation amount (not the sum of the amounts) into ASK.

Comment: Check my answer below for what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` to rank on the `SUM` of transactions per donos, then insert in "*donationrequests*" only rows whose ranking is 1.

```
INSERT INTO donationrequests 
WITH cte AS(
    SELECT *, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DONOR_ID 
                             ORDER     BY SUM(TRANSACTION_AMT) DESC
           ) AS rn
    FROM transactions
    GROUP BY DONOR_ID, TRANSACTION_AMT
)
SELECT DONOR_ID, TRANSACTION_AMT 
FROM cte 
WHERE rn = 1
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/exr5Wn4Ur5rr7wX43uW7YS/0).